Digital delay line understanding
I have a digital system described by following difference equation
$$y(k) = x(k - N_d)$$
I would say that it is a delay line. I was curious how does this system behave. So I have prepared a simple Scilab script where I have implemented the delay line as a filter with following transfer function
$$H(z) = z^{-Nd}$$
and I have at first tried to analyze its frequency response
// Nd samples delay
// system described by difference equation y(k) = x(k - Nd)
// system with transfer function  z^(-Nd) i.e. with impluse response 0 + 0*z^(-1) + 0*z(-2) + ... + // 0*z(-(Nd - 1)) + 1*z(-Nd)
Nd = 100;
// coefficients of the polynomial in the numerator of the transfer function
B = [zeros(1, Nd-1), 1];
// coefficients of the polynomial in the denominator of the transfer function
A = 1;

// Frequency response

// polynomial in the numerator of the transfer function in z^-1
num = poly(B, 'invz', 'c');
// polynomial in the denominator of the transfer function in z^-1
den = poly(A, 'invz', 'c');

// relative frequency - w*k*Ts = 2*pi*f/fs*k, maximum frequency is f = fs/2
// fr_max = f_max/fs = 0.5
fr = (0:0.0001:0.5);

// complex frequency response (transfer function in z^(-1))
// z = exp(s*T) = exp([sigma + j*omega]*T)
hf = freq(num, den, exp(-%i*2*%pi*fr));

// amplitude
magnitude = abs(hf);

// phase
hf_imag = imag(hf);
hf_real = real(hf);
phase = atand(hf_imag, hf_real);

scf();
plot(fr, magnitude, 'Linewidth', 2);
title('Magnitude');
xlabel('$f_r = \frac{f}{f_s}$');
ylabel('$Mag(H(z))\,(\mathrm{-})$');
xgrid;
scf();
plot(fr, phase, 'Linewidth', 2);
title('Phase');
xlabel('$f_r = \frac{f}{f_s}$');
ylabel('$Arg(H(z))\,(\mathrm{^\circ})$');
xgrid;



I have set $N_d = 100$, $T_s = 100\,\mu\mathrm{s}$, $f = 50\,\mathrm{Hz}$. So I have expected that the output of the delay line will be a $f = 50\,\mathrm{Hz}$ sine mirror image of the input along the time axis ($2\pi\frac{f}{f_s}\cdot N_d = 2\pi\frac{50}{10\,000}\cdot 100 = \pi \sim 10\,\mathrm{ms}$)
// Time response
    
Ts = 100*10^(-6); // sampling period (s)
fs = 1/Ts;        // sampling frequency (Hz)
f  = 50;          // input singnal frequency (Hz)
   
t = 0:0.00001:0.08;
x = sin(2*%pi*f.*t);
y = filter(B, A, x);
    
scf();
plot(t, x, 'b', t, y, 'r', 'Linewidth', 2);
xlabel('$t\,(\mathrm{s})$');
legend('$x$', '$y$');
xgrid;

But I have received a $f = 50\,\mathrm{Hz}$ sine with only $1\,\mathrm{ms}$ delay (i.e. ten times lower then was my intention)

I have probably made a mistake somewhere but I can't find out where.


t = 0:0.00001:0.08;

That's a sample period of $10 \mu s$ not $100 \mu s$. Probably a typo. In any case that should have been t = 0:Ts:0.08;
The total delay in seconds is is simply the product of sample period times the delay in samples, i.e. $\tau = N_d \cdot Ts = \frac{N_d}{f_s}$. It is independent of the frequency of the input signal. Since your sample rate (as coded) is only $10 \mu s$ the time delay will be $10 \mu s \cdot 100 = 1ms$ which is exactly what you got.

$2\pi\frac{f}{f_s}\cdot N_d = 2\pi\frac{50}{10\,000}\cdot 100 = \pi \sim 10\,\mathrm{ms}$

What you are calculating here is the phase delay in radiant, not the time delay in seconds. That phase delay is indeed $\pi$ so you should expect the delayed sine wave to be out of phase with the original one.
